# slideshow troubleshooting with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a slideshow and am having some trouble with the javascript.
When I click right once it works all good and then if I hit left it works too but then if I click on right again it should just go to the next image but it skips it and goes to the following. Anyone knows the solution?

```js
$('#droite').click(function() {
  if (photo == 4) {} else {
    $('#plateau-gallerie').animate({
      left: (-300 * photo) + 'px'
    }, 500);
    photo++;
  }
});
$('#gauche').click(function() {
  if (photo == 1) {} else {
    $('#plateau-gallerie').animate({
      left: (-300 * (photo - 2)) + 'px'
    }, 500);
    photo--;
  }
});
```

```css
#gallerie {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #999;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#plateau-gallerie {
  width: 1780px;
  float: left;
  top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#gallerie img {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 0px 0 80px;
  float: left;
}

.bouton {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 60px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: #444;
  opacity: 0.7;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.bouton:hover {
  background-color: #222;
}

#gauche{
 left:15px;
}

#droite{
 right:15px;
}
```

```html
<section id="gallerie">
  <button class="bouton" id="gauche"><</button>
  <section id="plateau-gallerie">
    <img src="img/pc-gallerie.jpg" alt="ordinateur">
    <img src="img/pc-gallerie.jpg" alt="ordinateur">
    <img src="img/pc-gallerie.jpg" alt="ordinateur">
    <img src="img/pc-gallerie.jpg" alt="ordinateur">
    <img src="img/pc-gallerie.jpg" alt="ordinateur">
    <img src="img/pc-gallerie.jpg" alt="ordinateur">
  </section>
  <button class="bouton" id="droite">></button>
</section>
```

Anyone got an idea on why this is?

Comment: can you put your code in a fiddle?

Comment: you want the whole code? because the part that is used is already written up there

Comment: Something that works and shows how your code operates

Comment: @NaguibIhab is right, IMHO the part you post is not really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have change the script, change the logic of slide left and right

Change the image width to 300px, and align it to center

```
#gallerie img {
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  width:300px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is the js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bqg2aheh/

```
$('#left').click(function() {
  if (!(photo < 0)) {  
   photo--;
    $('#plateau-gallerie').animate({
      left: (-300 * (photo)) + 'px'
    }, 500);
    console.log(photo + '  ' + (-300 * photo));
  }  
});

$('#right').click(function() {

  if (!(photo > 5)) {    
    photo++;
    $('#plateau-gallerie').animate({
      left: (-300 * photo) + 'px'
    }, 500);
    console.log(photo + '  ' + (-300 * photo));
  }  
});
```

please ignore the style

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce the behavior you are describing. I've created a fiddle (fiddle id eozpp6vo) with your code and the gallery seems to be working as expected.